# transition with position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` that is positioned absolute to my header-Tag. All is okay. With JavaScript I toggle the classes `display_block` and `display_none`, when I click on my button.

All works fine. 
The `div` that gets `display: none` and `display: block` with the toggle, gets the position `right: -100%` when it's `display:none`, and `right: 0` when its `display: block`.

Also works fine. But there is one problem. 
The div got `transition: all 1s ease-in-out` but I don't get that flow-motion. It's only here or gone. But no effect. Why?

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

#ware_cart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 35%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 
}

.display_none {
  display: none;
  right: -100%;
}

.display_block {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="ware_cart" class="display_none">
  <!-- stuff i like to show -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You can't transition `display`...so the item just snaps into place where it's *final* position is set.

Comment: Thank you!! Didnt know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Paulie D* said, you can not transition `display.`

Also, if the element starts at `right: 100%` there is no need to hide it.

Try this snippet:

```js
$('#toggle').click( function() {
  $('#ware_cart').toggleClass('move_right');
});
```

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

#ware_cart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  top: 80px;
  right: 100%;
  transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
}

#ware_cart.move_right {
  right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div id="ware_cart">
    stuff i like to show
  </div>
  <div id="toggle">
    Toggle it!
  </div> 
</header>
```